# Prevention of bootstrap inputs from moving to the left on small screens

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap. I got a problem. I am using the following classes: `form-control` and `form-inlinel`. And here is my html:

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="label label-primary moveDown">From should be less than To. Otherwise the answer will be wrong.</div>
    <div class="center">
    <div class="label label-primary">First interval</div>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" id="from1">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" id="to1">
    </div>
    <div class="label label-primary">Second interval</div>
    <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" id="from2">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" id="to2">
    </div>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="button">Show intersection</button>

    <div class="label label-primary moveDown">
        Intersection:
    </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label label-primary moveDown">From should be less than To. Otherwise the answer will be wrong.</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is css:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"]
{
    max-width: 100px;
    margin:0;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.container-fluid
{
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center !important;
}
.label
{
    font-size: 15px !important;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.center
{
    width: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.moveDown
{
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    display: block !important;
}

.label.moveDown
{
    display: inline-block !important;
}
```

And now about the problem. If you start the html on medium screen it is exactly okay and exactly what I want. However, try to resize and you will notice the problem. It is input the thing that is not satisfies me, it moves to left on small enough screen. If you know how I can tackle that help me, please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways you can make it stays centred.

1. In the element `input[type="text"]`, add the value `auto` in `margin` and it will stay centred.
2. Or you can add the property `display: inline-block;` in `input[type="text"]`.

It works both ways.

EDIT: The reason that it doesn't stay centred when reduced to mobile size is because Bootstrap has set the element `input` as block; pushing it to the left side.

```css
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"] {
  max-width: 100px;
  margin: 5px auto;
}

.container-fluid {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center !important;
}

.label {
  font-size: 15px !important;
  margin-bottom: 10px !important;
}

.center {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.moveDown {
  margin-top: 5px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

.label.moveDown {
  display: inline-block !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="label label-primary moveDown">From should be less than To. Otherwise the answer will be wrong.</div>
    <div class="center">
      <div class="label label-primary">First interval</div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" id="from1">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" id="to1">
      </div>
      <div class="label label-primary">Second interval</div>
      <div class="form-inline">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="From" id="from2">

        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="To" id="to2">
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="button">Show intersection</button>

      <div class="label label-primary moveDown">
        Intersection:
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="label label-primary moveDown">From should be less than To. Otherwise the answer will be wrong.</div>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you change this part of your CSS to read:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"]
{
   max-width: 100px;
   margin:0 auto;
   margin-top: 5px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

The `Margin: 0 Auto;`  attribute force center the inputs for you!

It could even be shortened to:

```
input[type="text"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="email"],
input[type="tel"],
input[type="select"]
{
   max-width: 100px;
   margin:5px auto;

}
```

To take into account the 5px margin you've added.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks very much for the attention. It helped.

Comment: @YaroslavTrofimov No problem!

Answer (score 0):

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0t4eg8tn/)

I removed the `form-inline` and changed it to it's own custom class (I just called it `inputs` for the sake of this example). Then I added simply added this CSS:

```
.inputs {
padding-left: 3.5em;
}
```

You can slide the fiddle back and forth now and see that it stays in the center.

Comment: Thanks very much for the attention. However, your practice seems for me to be bad. One should use only percentage or in the worst case px, but using em especially for padding sounds substandard.